# ASP.net AJAX Search

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am looking for an example of using ASP.net AJAX to show a 'live' filtering of a repeater control based on what is being typed into a textbox.  I have seen stuff using the Web Client Software Factory but am more interested in something that doesn't require an additional library.

Answer (score 1):

The asp.net ajax control toolkit has one [here](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx).

If you don't like that one, searching google for "Ajax Autocomplete" gives lots of decent looking results, unless I am mistaking what it is you want to do.

Comment: I believe that method binds directly to a textbox, I want something that affects the datasource of a repeater.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little confused as to what AJAX entails. If you want the filtering to interface with the server control's datasource, then it would not by definition be AJAX.

Live filtering a databound control the way you want is ill-advised, I think. For each iteration you'd have to re-bind the control, which would create a tremendous amount of overhead.

You'll need to find a way to do this client-side, with javascript. It could simply hide items within the repeater-created markup as they are filtered out, although how exactly this would be accomplished depends entirely on what html you're generating with the repeater.